# JPanel appears as a small white box

Tags: java, swing

I am in the early stages of trying to create a Java 2d graphics paint program.  I'm using a flow layout, and I'm using three panels.  The first two are rows of buttons, combo boxes, etc. and the third is meant to be a large, blank, white panel that will be used to paint on.  The first two panels show up beautifully, but the paint panel appears as a small white box next to the second button panel.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class DrawingApp extends JFrame
{
    private final topButtonPanel topPanel = new topButtonPanel();
    private final bottomButtonPanel bottomPanel = new bottomButtonPanel();
    private final PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

    public DrawingApp()
    {
        super("Java 2D Drawings");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(topPanel);
        add(bottomPanel);
        add(paintPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DrawingApp frame = new DrawingApp();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(750,500);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}

public class topButtonPanel extends JPanel
{

    private final String[] names = {"Line", "Oval", "Rectangle"};

    private final JButton undo = new JButton("Undo");
    private final JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private final JLabel shape = new JLabel("Shape:");
    private final JComboBox<String> shapesComboBox = new JComboBox(names);
    private final JCheckBox filled = new JCheckBox("Filled");

    public topButtonPanel()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(undo);
        add(clear);
        add(shape);
        shapesComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        add(shapesComboBox);
        add(filled);
    }
}


public class bottomButtonPanel extends JPanel
{

    private final JCheckBox useGradient = new JCheckBox("Use Gradient");
    private final JButton firstColor = new JButton("1st Color");
    private final JButton secondColor = new JButton("2nd Color");
    private final JLabel lineWidthLabel = new JLabel("Line Width:");
    private final JLabel dashLengthLabel = new JLabel("Dash Length:");
    private final JTextField lineWidthField = new JTextField(2);
    private final JTextField dashLengthField = new JTextField(2);
    private final JCheckBox filled = new JCheckBox("Dashed");

    public bottomButtonPanel()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(useGradient);
        add(firstColor);
        add(secondColor);
        add(lineWidthLabel);
        add(lineWidthField);
        add(dashLengthLabel);
        add(dashLengthField);
        add(filled);
    }
} 

public class PaintPanel extends JPanel
{

    public PaintPanel()
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setSize(700,400);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class topButtonPanel extends JPanel` Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. Thhough note that there is no reason here to extend `JPanel` since no functionality is changing - just use an instance of one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's a misunderstanding of how the Swing API works.

Swing relies (heavily) on the layout management API which is used to make decisions about how large components should be (and where they should be placed)

Using `setSize` is pointless, as the layout manager will make it's own decisions about what it thinks the size of your component should be and will adjust it accordingly.

You can make suggestions to the layout manager about how large you'd like the component to be using `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`, for example

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel
{

    public PaintPanel()
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(700, 400);
    }
}
```

Just remember, layout managers are well within their right to ignore these values, so you need to have a better understanding of how these managers work

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details