# Swing showing white box when I try to add more than one component on frame

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing java swing application. I try to add 2 JPanels on my main JFrame.

My main JPanel class:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    //mouse variables here
    //Point mPt = new Point(0,0);

    public DrawingPanel() {
        setBackground(COLOURBACK);
        MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
        addMouseListener(ml);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
....
....
....
}
```

is working fine when I add as the only component on main frame. But when I try to add another JPanel on the frame my DrawingPanel appears as small white box.

```
private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hex Testing 4");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        JPanel aggregationFrame = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        aggregationFrame.add(panel);
        aggregationFrame.add(new JLabel("Enter username:"));
        content.add(aggregationFrame);
        //this.add(panel);  -- cannot be done in a static context
        //for hexes in the FLAT orientation, the height of a 10x10 grid is 1.1764 * the width. (from h / (s+t))
        frame.setSize( (int)(SCRSIZE/1.23), SCRSIZE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

It looks like this

[image: result]

I tried to add getPreferredSize() method to DrawingPanel as was suggested in [JPanel appears as a small white box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189948/jpanel-appears-as-a-small-white-box) question but it didn't work well.

Can you help me with the problem please?

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the layout and now I see a half of my JPanel. I think the problem relates to fixed sizes of JPanels and JFrame. Will investigate it.

[image: update]

Answer (score 1):

So, I took your, out-of-context code, hobbled together a runnable variant and ... had no issues.  Which suggests that the issue is somewhere in the code you're not showing us.  Instead of posting "snippets" of incomplete code, which raises more questions, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which can be compiled and run, which demonstrates the issue you are having

## An example, which runs and works...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hex Testing 4");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        JPanel aggregationFrame = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        aggregationFrame.add(panel);
        aggregationFrame.add(new JLabel("Enter username:"));
        content.add(aggregationFrame);
        //this.add(panel);  -- cannot be done in a static context
        //for hexes in the FLAT orientation, the height of a 10x10 grid is 1.1764 * the width. (from h / (s+t))
        frame.pack();
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    //mouse variables here
    //Point mPt = new Point(0,0);

    private int width = 200;
    private int height = 200;

    public DrawingPanel() {
      setBackground(Color.BLACK);
//    MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
//    addMouseListener(ml);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my components size. It seems like it didnt fit into main frame and was cut. I set dynamic frame size and now it works well.